# Optimisation question - rectangle under curve

Tags: calculus

[image]

I've done part a:

i. $(\pi-x,0)$

ii.$(\pi-2x)\sin x$

Not sure how to do b though. Can someone explain what to do?

Comment: take your answer from part a.ii and differentiate. The area will be optimal when the derivative of the area function is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Define the area function of the rectangle:
$f(x) = (\pi -2x) \sin x$

We'll find the maximum by deriving the function:
$f'(x)=\pi \cos x -2 \sin x -2x \cos x$

The maximum is given when $f'(x) = 0$, i.e $2 \sin x = (\pi-2x)\cos x$ and by dividing in $\cos x$ we obtain that $f'(x)=0$ when $2 \tan x=\pi-2x$